# Calling enum method in main

Tags: java

```
NORTH("north"),
SOUTH("south"),
WEST("west"),
EAST("east");

String direction;

private RoomDirection(String direction){
     this.direction=direction;
}

public String getDirection(){
    return this.direction;
}

public  boolean isSecondCommand(String aString){

    aString=aString.toUpperCase();
    for(RoomDirection dir :RoomDirection.values()){

        if(aString.equalsIgnoreCase(dir.direction))
            return true;

    }

    return false;
}

boolean static c= RoomDirection.isSecondCommand(word2);
if(commands.isCommand(word1)&&c.isSecondCommand(word2))
    return new Command(word1,word2);`
```

hello guys iam new in java and iam writing a zork game as a university student...i want to put the directions north west east and south in enum file and then take them on main....i have searched a lot this two days....i came up with smth like this ....

error in calling the method isSecondCommand of enum class RoomDirection in my main class

Comment: i have also put the } after return false ;and the enum class is called public enum RoomDirection

Comment: What is a "second coming"? Why use `toUpperCase` and `equalsIgnoreCase`?

Comment: u got a point it was a copy paste from other code....but that doesnt solve the problem...i got an issue on my call in the main class and i dont get what....the return type is boolean (true,false ) but it tells me error....

Comment: the edit cause some problems on the submit and it finds me errors ....thats the only way i could put the code in this article...iam new to this also

Comment: Kindly edit your Question

Comment: Sotirios Delimanolis can u suggest smth about the call error?:)

Comment: It looks like you want `isSecondCommand` to be static. i.e. `public static boolean isSecondCommand(...`

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code as below. And I think this is what you want to do.

```
enum RoomDirection {
    NORTH, SOUTH, WEST, EAST
} 

public class TestEnum {
    String direction;

    RoomDirection roomDirection;

    private void RoomDirection(String direction) {
        this.direction = direction;
    }

    public String getDirection() {
        return this.direction;
    }

    public boolean isSecondCommand(String d) {
        for (RoomDirection dir : RoomDirection.values()) {
            if(d.equalsIgnoreCase(dir.name())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestEnum te = new TestEnum();
        System.out.println(te.isSecondCommand("abcd"));     // false, because RoomDirection doesn't contain a value named abcd
        System.out.println(te.isSecondCommand("north"));    // true
        System.out.println(te.isSecondCommand("NORTH"));    // true
    }
}
```

isSecondCommand() is a function which allows you to input a String and test if the enum RoomDirection contains this String.

Comment: Your `isSecondCommand` has essentially become `d != null`. Any non null RoomDirection *has* to be in the values() array for that enum.

Comment: at the main class when i try to write your code testEnum is transforming on RoomDirection.TestEnum and when i try to put new RoomDirection.TestEnum it writes an error RoomDirection is not an enclosing class

Comment: i made the TestEnum public static and it worked with no errors...but it seems like it doesnt make the work doen....for example if i put NORTH it doesnt find it......

Comment: May I ask which java compiler version you use?

Comment: I tried jdk version 1.7, and 1.8. Both compilers work correctly with my code.